# Why Does a join in LINQ generate extra objects in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I know the title sounds cooky, and I am sure there is a very easy explanation for this but i am losing mind at this point.

I am doing an intersect query using Linq:

```
    var result = from item1 in em1.EmailBindingList
                 join item2 in em2.EmailBindingList

                 on item1.Header equals item2.Header
                 select item1;
```

(both em1 and em2 have 15875 items and both are identical) The above should give me a result with 15875 items.

Yet, I get 15879

Look at pic. I really don't get it.! [image: Why]

See  cdhowie comment below. He solved this for me. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you have some elements in one or both lists that have the same `Header`, resulting in a cartesian product.  What is the output of: `em1.EmailBindingList.Select(i => i.Header).Distinct().Count()`, and the same for `em2`?  If either of these produce a value under 15875, then this is almost certainly the reason.

Comment: @cdhowie Thats a good idea! Completely didn't think about it. Ill try this now

Comment: @cdhowie yep! that is totally on the spot, they each have 15873, making 2 x 2 = extra 4. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have some elements in one or both lists that have the same Header, resulting in a cartesian product.

You can verify this by looking at the result of `em1.EmailBindingList.Select(i => i.Header).Distinct().Count()`, and the same for em2. If either of these produce a value under 15875, then this is almost certainly the reason.